# How to perform oauth when doing twitter scraping with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, twitter-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve 100 recent tweets of a user. It is working well with tweepy module in Python. But how can I do the same with requests in python. I want to do:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxx&count=100')
```

Here how to do the authentication with client key, client secret, access token and access secret, before sending this request?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) as described in requests [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-1-authentication).

OAuth:

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
auth = OAuth1(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

Get tweets:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=stackoverflow&count=100', auth=auth)
for tweet in r.json():
  print tweet['text']
```