# Scraping Twitter data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have tried to scrape twitter data using BeautifulSoup and requests library. I tried to log in first using BeautifulSoup and then scrape the required page. But it is not working. I didn't get the mistake what I have done.

I am adding this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session_rqst=requests.session()
url="https://twitter.com/login"
r=requests.get(url)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
token=soup.find("input",{"name":"authenticity_token"})
payload = {"username": "test_user", "password": "test_password"}
result=session_rqst.post(url, data=payload, headers = 
dict(referer="https://twitter.com/"))
all=result.content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(all,"html.parser")
page=requests.get("https://twitter.com/akhiltaker/following")
page.content
soup1=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
```

How I can scrape followers list from the webpage?

Comment: You should use https://developer.twitter.com/. Twitter provides an api for such activities.

Comment: **You need to change your twitter password immediately**. Even though it's been edited it out, anyone with enough rep can still see it.

Comment: Thanq for informing, i didnt notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scraping twitter via `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` manually, use the [twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en.html).

You can get the followers of an account directly, see the docs here: [api-reference/get-followers-list](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-list) which gives you your data as json.

There are [various Python libraries for twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries.html), which you can use to for your purpose.

---

**Edit:** Regarding your question to `BeautifulSoup`: It looks like you cannot login to twitter that simple, so your response probably contains only some login/error page, but not your follower list. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346254/5276734) on how to login to twitter via Python.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer (in fact, it's already a comment). Yes, the Twitter API is the way to go, but that has nothing to do with BeautifulSoup.